# Como plantear una consulta mysql comparar dos diferentes tablas que muestre diferencias

Tags: base-de-datos, tablas, comparaciones

esta es mi duda, tengo dos tablas cuyo contenido son iguales, las uso para comparar registros mes a mes, las tablas se llaman bd1 y bd2, quiero una consulta que me verifique los campos de las dos columnas y me regrese los resultados de aquellos campos donde existan diferencias entre la informacion de db1 y db2, tengo esta consulta, pero no me funciona y quisiera que por favor me den luces son porque estos planteando mal mi consulta, Gracias.

Esta es la consulta que tengo

```
SELECT db1. * , 'CON CAMBIOS'estatus
FROM db1
INNER JOIN db2 WHERE 
db1.id != db2.id
AND db1.rank != db2.rank
AND db1.country != db2.country
AND db1.population != db2.population
AND db1.date_of_estimate != db2.date_of_estimate
AND db1.powp != db2.powp
```

Comment: Tambien probe con este operador <> en vez de !=

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo el error está en el join, primero tienes que juntar los registros de ambas tablas por el id, así que el join debe ser donde los dos id coincidan:

```
select db1. * , 'CON CAMBIOS'estatus from db1
inner join db2 on db1.id = db2.id
```

Luego si vienen los where, ya que se logró la unión ahora si revisas los campos a ver si están diferentes:

```
where db1.country != db2.country
...
```

Fíjate como lo dejé acá:

[Enlace a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9502b/3)